# Dog acting strange about stairs

Tags: dogs, behavior

I have a 12 year old Golden and she is acting strange about the stairs.  We have a set of stairs at both the front and back doors as our house sits up 8'.  Each set of stairs has a landing 1/2 way up.  She will climb the first set of stairs to the landing but seems confused when she needs to climb the next set. The stairs out back were rebuilt just for her a few years ago with a long wide rise but she has stopped using these also. She climbs to the first landing and that's as far as she will go. If she starts out on her right foot she's ok but getting her to do that is almost impossible.  We built a ramp but she refuses to use it. Guess I need to install an elevator to get my baby girl inside.

Comment: I had a guy that stopped wanting to climb and it turned out he had a ruptured tendon in a rear knee.

Comment: Have you tried getting her to walk up stair somewhere otside, in an unknown building, generally not home? It ma yhelp to know if it is THESE stairs she refuses, or she refuses ALL stairs except the ones that she decided are fine.